# Как добавить слушателя, вызываемого не по Enter, к JTextField

Tags: java

Есть такой код:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JTextField t = new JTextField();
        frame.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, t);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        t.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String s = t.getText();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

`ActionListener` следит за `JTextField` и передает данные только после нажатия <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
В программе есть несколько полей `JTextField`. Как сделать так, чтобы написанный текст считывался, даже если пользователь не нажимал каждый раз <kbd>Enter</kbd>?

Или как по-другому сделать форму для заполнения (с полями для ввода данных и кнопкой отправить)? По типу как это делается в HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: `textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() ` отловит как раз эти изменения. не рассматривали это твариант?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вам необходимо добавить [DocumentListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentListener.html). чтобы отловить изменения.

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JTextField t = new JTextField();
    frame.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, t);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(200, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    t.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            print();
        }
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            print();
        }
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            print();
        }

        public void print() {
            System.out.println(t.getText());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Спасибо!!! Помогло)))

Comment: всегда пожалуйста